# Слежка за изменением тхт файла в папке

Tags: c#

Есть значит папка на рабочем столе. В этой папке есть пустой тхт файл. По моему алгоритму, когда софт нашел "что-то", он это "что-то" в этот тхт записывает. А софт который работает в фоне следит за изменением этого тхт, в котором должно записаться "что-то". Как только этот пустой тхт из первый строчки вопроса изменён, софт, который следит за изменением **создает 5 скажем пустых тхт** и когда создал, и сам выключился...я вроде все понял. Вопрос как создать этот софт который следит...

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону систем контроля версий - Git, SVN, например. 
Если использовать их не вариант, то попробуйте сделать по подобию - создавайте копию первого файла и по таймеру сверяйте фоновым софтом рабочий файл и его копию.

Comment: Если оба этих софта ваши, то лучше, чтобы они общались не через запись/чтение файла, а более прямым способом. Например, через именованный канал (named pipe).

Answer (score 3):

Вопрос у вас довольно общий, поэтому и ответ тоже будет общий:

- Для слежения за файлами используйте [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx).

  ```
  private void StartWatchingFile()
  {
      var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
      watcher.Filter = "some_file.txt";
      watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
      watcher.Changed += OnFileChanged;
  }

  private void OnFileChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
  {
      // содержимое файла изменилось, ваши действия, затем выключение
      Environment.Exit(0);
  }
  ```
- Подобные "следящие" приложения удобнее оформлять [в виде
  Windows-сервисов](http://wladm.narod.ru/C_Sharp/services.html) (в этом случае завершать свою работу лучше вызовом метода [`Stop()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.stop.aspx)).

Comment: @anreycha а что в юзингах надо добавить ?

Comment: @komra23 нажмите Ctrl+. и Студия вам подскажет. Или смотрите в МСДНе.